# Displaying primary key from database in order from least to greatest in C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

In my database the primary keys are in order from least to greatest (1,2,3, etc.) but when I load them into my combobox they are displayed out of order. I'm sure there is an easy fix to this, but I'm stuck.

```
    public void fillComboBox()
    {
        try
        {
            // query to pull invoice ids
            string sql = "SELECT PersonalInfo.[ID] FROM PersonalInfo order by ID"; 

            // adapter to send query to database
            OleDbDataAdapter daInvoices = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn);
            // fill dataset
            daInvoices.Fill(cusNumDS, "PersonalInfo");

            // declare data source for invoice id combo box
            custCB.DataSource = cusNumDS.Tables[0];
            custCB.DisplayMember = "PersonalInfo";
            custCB.ValueMember = "ID";
            // bind data source to combo box
            custCB.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", cusNumDS.Tables[0], "ID");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error message if trouble pulling invoice ids from database
            MessageBox.Show("Trouble pulling invoices from database because: " + ex,
                "Database Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ali Rashidi. I tried this, but it didn't work :/

Comment: What do you mean by "Out of Order"?

Comment: In what order are they displayed? What is the data type of the ID column?

Comment: The combo box displays everything that begins with 1 first, the 2 etc. It looks like: 1, 11,12, 13...2, 20, 21, etc. The data type is double.

Comment: One possible try may be to sort the dataTable defaultView before binding to the combobox in your C# code. More importantly you need to make your PK dataType as int - its better than double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment, you say..

> No the combobox displays everything that begins with 1, such as 1, 10, 11, 12...2, 20, 21, 22 etc. I want it to be in order from lowest to highest.

This means a [Lexicographical Ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) for text is being used during the sorting. Now, there are two reasons (I can think of) that would cause this.

1. The KEY might be a *char/varchar* column and the ordering is applied by the database. If this is the case, then the following query should work:

   ```sql
   SELECT PersonalInfo.[ID] FROM PersonalInfo
   ORDER BY CAST(id AS INT)
   -- for MS Access maybe: ORDER BY CInt(id)
   ```

   And if it does fix the problem then the scheme should probably be fixed!
2. A sort might be applied *after* the query, such as within the ComboBox itself! Make sure that [Sorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is false.

   > [The Sorted] property specifies whether the ComboBox sorts existing entries and add new entries to the appropriate sorted position in the list. You can use this property to automatically sort items in a ComboBox .. The sort is case-insensitive and in *alphabetically ascending* order.

.. or it could be a combination of both! Also, make sure that the code being run/tested is the *latest* version and is *really* being used.

Comment: custCB.DisplayMember = "PersonalInfo";
            custCB.ValueMember = "ID";     Only one field is selected from database. is it right to assign PersonalInfo to the property DisplayMember of comboBox?

Comment: @AliRashidi Check in the Designer Properties as well - you'll know what the problem is based on if the first query update "fixes" the ordering or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed my code to match what you suggested, but this did not work either. I checked to make sure Sorted = false, but still no luck

Comment: @Learnin2Code And did you try the query with `ORDER BY CAST(id as INT)`? Also, in MS Access it might be `ORDER BY CInt(id)`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this: string sql = "SELECT PersonalInfo.[ID] FROM PersonalInfo ORDER BY CAST(ID AS INT)";

Comment: @Learnin2Code Well, then you have me stumped - are you sure the code is being *recompiled* and *used* correctly? An old version might explain the behavior. (Also, check `ORDER BY CInt(id)`, as I believe it's an MS Access specialism.)

Comment: @Learnin2Code One last suggestion: add `custCB.Sorted = false;` right above where the DataSource is set, within the same method *and* have the CAST/CInt in the ORDER BY.

Comment: I'm going to try to change the datatype in Access and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT PersonalInfo.[ID] FROM PersonalInfo order by 1 ASC
```

try this....

Comment: Thank you X - Developer. I tried this, but it did not work :/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PersonalInfo.[ID] FROM PersonalInfo order by ID ASC
```

put ASC at the end of your select statement

Comment: No the combobox displays everything that begins with 1, such as 1, 10, 11, 12...2, 20, 21, 22 etc. I want it to be in order from lowest to highest.

Comment: OK i see. Do I need to change the datatype in Access or convert it in C#?